# Хранить интерфейс сайта в одном файле или в нескольких

Tags: php

В настоящий момент интерфейс сайта хранится в нескольких php файлах, в массивах типа:

```
$text_array_001 = array('Запись 1');
$text_array_002 = array('Запись 2');
// и т. д.
```

Часть этих файлов подключается к страницам сайта сразу, по одному файлу на каждую страницу, остальные php файлы дёргаются AJAX запросами, после выполнения которых изменяются отдельные элементы интерфейса. Всего php языковых файлов скопилось больше сотни. В каждом из них содержится свой набор языковых записей. Я посчитал нужным поступить именно так, поскольку гнался за производительностью. Но мой заказчик остался недоволен, поскольку по его мнению множество языковых php файлов создаёт неудобства в поиске и редактировании информации. В итоге сошлись на создании одного, общего языкового php файла.

Если изъять интерфейс из всех имеющихся php файлов, а затем сложить в одну кучу, то получится довольно увесистый php файл. Будет крайне неэффективно подключаться к этому файлу, при каждом небольшом AJAX запросе.

Подумав как это можно осуществить, у меня возникла следующая идея. При каждом AJAX запросе мы будем передавать в наш языковой файл переменную, в соответствии с которой, будет объявлен только тот кусок кода, который нам необходим. Пример:

```
$my_var = $_POST['var1']; // пришла переменная от AJAX

// проверяем переменную
if ($my_var == 'my1') {
    // объявляем массив текстовых записей для my1
    $text_array_001 = array('Запись 1');
    $text_array_002 = array('Запись 2');
} elseif ($my_var == 'my2') {
    // объявляем массив текстовых записей для my2
    $text_array_003 = array('Запись 3');
    $text_array_004 = array('Запись 4');
} elseif ($my_var == 'и т. д.') {
    // и т. д. до бесконечности
}
// дальше пусть идёт тело скрипта и его функции
include('my_script.php');
```

Вопрос состоит в следующем. Языковой php файл у нас получился объёмом 10 Mb. Будет ли он грузиться в оперативную память весь или же в оперативку пойдут только те массивы, которые удовлетворят одно из условий `if, elseif`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думается, не самое оптимальное решение. Чем больше оправданного деления на обособленные используемые части, тем лучше - как и функция/файл, которая, в идеале, должна решать одну-единственную задачу.

Если проблема только в редактировании множества файлов, то оптимальнее будет разработать разветвленный и пусть сложный интерфейс взаимодействия/редактирования всех сразу, в части относящейся - например, дополнительно разбить, при необходимости, имеющиеся на еще более атомарные логические сущности и разработать систему идентификаторов, которые позволяли бы из интерфейса подключать к одновременному (и обособленному тоже) редактированию нужные файлы.
Это самый оптимальный подход по производительности и расширяемости, управлению и структуризации.

Подгрузка частично из большого одного файла не получится - сначала будет считан весь файл, потом выбрано нужное.

Есть вариант использовать sqlite, в этом случае - тогда выборка будет возможна на примемлемых условиях - но это не оптимально - оптимальное в первой части, имхо.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы используете AJAX загрузку, то в дело может включиться мини-API, которая будет принимать заголовок `Accept-Language: ru` ([ссылка](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language)).

API будет обрабатывтаь ваш запрос, и исходя из заголовка будет тянуть из базы соответсвующую запись, примерно так: `SELECT * from text WHERE id=1 AND lang='ru'` и запрос будет возвращен в JSON формате - данное решение упростит вам жинь в дальнейшем, а так же даст возможность редактирования имеющихся и добавления новых записей в бд. Рекоменудую прочитать [данную статью](https://habr.com/ru/post/195468/) про мультиязычность.

P.S.: Не обязательно писать API, оно является одним из "best practitcs". Вы можете реализовать все на сервере не конструируя новый отдельный сервис(API).